# How to install just security updates via the command line on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, updates, aptitude

I can't find anything on Google that could help me to use aptitude to install only security updates using command line on Ubuntu.

I tried this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates but it installed everything and not only the security updates!

How can I just install security updates?

Comment: Duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/q/194/62688

Answer (score 1):

Check and adjust /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrade .  Did you replace 'karmic' with the code name of your Ubuntu?

Comment: Hello,
I will try that, sorry for my late response, I did not see my question was moved from stackoverflow to superuser :-)